# How to do advanced String templating in Javascript with loops and control statements

Tags: javascript, npm

Basically at run time i get an array like following

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
```

and i need to build a JSON String like following

```
{
    "color" : {
        "name" : "foo",
        "properties" : {
            ...
        }
    },
    "green" : {
        "name" : "foo",
        "properties" : {
            ...
        }
    },
    "blue" : {
        "name" : "foo",
        "properties" : {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any String templating framework which supports loops and control statements to build a JSON String like above

Answer (score 3):

Fit.UIs templating engine is simple and intuitive:

http://fitui.org/Core-Template.html

You can load HTML both embedded and from an external HTML file - example:

```js
var t = new Fit.Template(true);

// Load embedded HTML
tpl.LoadHtml(`
    <h1>{[MyHeadline]}</h1><br>
    <p>{[Description]}</p>
    <ul>
        <!-- LIST MyItems -->
            <li>{[ItemTitle]}</li>
        <!-- /LIST MyItems -->
    </ul>
`);
// Load HTML from external HTML file
t.LoadUrl("view.html", function(sender)
{
    // Template is ready to be populated
    t.Content.MyHeadline = "Welcome";
    t.Content.Description = "This is a test..";

    for (var i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
    {
        var item = t.Content.MyItems.AddItem();
        item.ItemTitle = "Item " + i;
    }

    t.Update();
});

t.Render(document.body);
```

Obviously you will need to populate your JSON object yourself, but that seems fairly easy to achieve on top of Fit.Template.

There is an NPM package available here if you like including Typings to enable intellisense:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fit-ui

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Nunjucks package. It supports both javascript & npm libraries. 
The template can be declared as follow (named it as colors.template):

```
{
    {% for color in colors %}
    "{{ color }}"  : {
      hashCode : "#CCC"
     }
    {% else %}
    {% endfor %}
}
```

And you can parse the json template as follows:

```
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.configure({ autoescape: true });
var output = nunjucks.render('colors.template', {colors : ['red', 'green', 'blue'] });
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain javascript:

```
function arrayToJSONProp(array, json) {
  var strJson = JSON.stringify(json);
  var output = "{";
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var elem = array[i];
    output += '"' +elem +'" : ' +strJson +", ";
  }
  return JSON.parse(output.slice(0, -2) +"}");
}

var colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]; // Colors array
var prop = { // JSON obj input
  "name" : "foo",
  "properties" : {
    "ran": "test"
  }
}

console.log(arrayToJSONProp(colors, prop)); // Output of JSON obj
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6wka5x9/3/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am actually looking for a generic solution with a templating library.